# Pythonic type coercion from input

Tags: python, type-safety

My context is a very simple filter-like program that streams lines from an input file into an output file, filtering out lines the user (well, me) doesn't want. The filter is rather easy, simply requiring a particular value for some 'column' in the input file. Options are easily expressed with `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument('-e', '--example', type=int, metavar='EXAMPLE', 
    help='require a value of %(metavar)s for column "example"')
```

There's a few of these, all typed. As the actual filter gets a line at some point, the question whether to include such a line is simple: split the line and check all the required filters:

```
c1, c2, c3, *_ = line.split('\t')
c1, c2, c3 = int(c1), int(c2), int(c3) # ← this line bugs me

if args.c1 and args.c1 != c1:
    return False
```

The second line of which bugs me a bit: as the values are initially strings and I need them to be something else, the types need to be changed. Although short, I'm not entirely convinced this is the best solution. Some other options:

- create a separate function to hide the thing that bugs me;
- remove the `type=` declarations from the options (also removes automatic user input validation);
- coerce the arguments back to `str`s and do the comparison with `str`s (would lead to about the same as what I've got).

Which of the options available would be the 'best', 'most pythonic', 'prettiest'? Or am I just overthinking this...

Comment: `int()` skips leading and trailing whitespace and leading zeros. So, a string comparison is not quite the same. Which do you need?

Comment: I need the numeric value. My data doesn't contain extraneous whitespace or zeroes, thought that doesn't much matter for the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Possible bugs

I can't be certain that these are bugs, but they look dodgy to me:

1. You can't filter on the number 0, because if `args.c1` is 0, then it will test false and so you'll never compare it to `c1`. Is this a problem? If it is, you ought to compare `args.c1` explicitly against `None`.
2. If the string `c1` cannot be converted to an integer, then `int(c1)` will raise `ValueError`. Is this what you want? Would it be better to treat this case as "not matching the filter"?
3. If `line` has fewer than three fields, the assignment to `c1, c2, c3, *_` will raise `ValueError`. Is this what you want? Would it be better to treat this case as "not matching the filter"?

#### 2. Suggested improvement

Fixing the possible bugs listed above:

```
def filter_field(filter, field):
    """
    Return True if the string `field` passes `filter`, which is
    either None (meaning no filter), or an int (meaning that 
    `int(field)` must equal `filter`).
    """
    try:
        return filter is None or filter == int(field)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

and then:

```
filters = [args.c1, args.c2, args.c3]
fields = line.split('\t')
if len(fields) < len(filters):
    return False
if not all(filter_field(a, b) for a, b in zip(filters, fields)):
    return False
```

Comment: 1: figured that as well, though my current context will never 'require' a falsy value. 2: valid point, crashing isn't good, even though I'd expect only integers. 3: also a valid point, though my lines contain far more than 3 values in reality.
Furthermore, I like your idea of using `all` and `zip`; does feel prettier to me :)